# How to get customized gnome live environment NOT to revert to original when live system is installed

Tags: linux-mint, gnome, system-installation, iso

I've customized a version of Linux Mint, including changing the desktop environment to GNOME, changing the wallpaper, adding shell user themes, extensions, changing the cursor, changing the icons, changing the plymouth theme, and changing the OS-release file (to change the name of the distro in the about section in settings).

I then used a tool called `penguin's eggs` to turn the system into an installable live ISO file.

However, when I try to install this file on another computer, the live environment is perfect, just how I want it. But when I install it onto the computer (the `penguin's eggs` tool installs `calamares` on the live system), then most of my customization are gone. Things like the plymouth theme and the edited OS-release file are still there, and it has the GNOME desktop, but the themes and icons, and most of my other customizations, such as extensions like Dash to Dock at the top of the screen, are gone.

Is there any way to make the live environment install as is, with all user data and installed themes? It worked with KDE, but GNOME seems to not include themes once installed.

**IMPORTANT: Please don't be that person to not offer a solution but mark the question as replied to just to say "Don't make an iso, make a script/backup. It's *essential* for my use case that everything is ready out of the box after you install the ISO.** Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Configuration of Eggs section in the [user's guide](https://penguins--eggs-net.translate.goog/docs/Tutorial/eggs-users-guide?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp&_x_tr_hist=true)?

Comment: Some information about the command and options you used to create your ISO would be useful for troubleshooting.  Also, some information about how you are making your customizations.  The default of `penguins-eggs` is to remove all of the user data and depending on how you did your customizations, might have removed all everything you changed.

Comment: I used the command, "eggs produce --clone", which should have preserved user data. Keep in mind that it did seem to do that, as some things were there, but seemed not to be applied once you installed (they were applied in the live enviroment). It seems to be something with GNOME, as when I previously did this with KDE Neon, it worked perfectly. Any help is appriciated.